# Delegate error in C#

Tags: c#

My code is as follows:

```
class PropertyRetrievalClass
{
    public delegate object getProperty(string input);

    public object get_Chart_1(string iput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(iput);
        return "";
    }
    public object get_Chart_2(string iput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(iput);
        return "";
    }

    public PropertyRetrievalClass() { }
}

public static void Main()
        {
            int i = 1;
            PropertyRetrievalClass obj = new PropertyRetrievalClass();

            Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass), obj, "get_chart_" + i.ToString());
            string output=  del("asldkl");
        }
```

It is giving me an error saying "error CS0118: 'del' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'"

What should I do to use this delegate? I want to call any of "get_chart_1" or "get_chart_2" function and both of them take a string input?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

- A `Delegate` object is not a method, so you need to use a method on the `Delegate` object to invoke the method it refers
- The first argument to `CreateDelegate` should be the delegate type, not the class containing a method you want to invoke.

Full working example:

```
public delegate void ParamLess();
class SomeClass
{
    public void PrintStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("stuff");
    }
}
internal class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<int, int> dict = null;
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new SomeClass();
        Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParamLess), obj, 
                "PrintStuff", false);
        del.DynamicInvoke(); // invokes SomeClass.PrintStuff, which prints "stuff"
    }
}
```

In your case, the `Main` method should look like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int i = 1;
    PropertyRetrievalClass obj = new PropertyRetrievalClass();

    Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty), 
        obj, 
        "get_Chart_" + i.ToString());
    string output =  (string)del.DynamicInvoke("asldkl");
}
```

**Update**
Note that `CreateDelegate` is case sensitive on the method name, unless you tell it not to.

```
// this call will fail, get_chart should be get_Chart
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty), 
        obj, 
        "get_chart_" + i.ToString());


// this call will succeed
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty), 
        obj, 
        "get_Chart_" + i.ToString());


// this call will succeed, since we tell CreateDelegate to ignore case
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty), 
        obj, 
        "get_chart_" + i.ToString(),
        true);
```

Comment: Got an exception: Error binding to target method :-(

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have addressed the problem with your code, but I wanted to offer an alternative.

If there are a limited, finite number of methods that your retrieval class is choosing from, and they have the same signatures, this can be done much more efficiently without using reflection:

```
public int MethodIndex {get;set;}
public static void Main()
{
    PropertyRetrievalClass obj = new PropertyRetrievalClass();
    Func<string,object> getChartMethod;
    switch(MethodIndex) 
    {
        case 1:
            getChartMethod = obj.get_chart_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            getChartMethod = obj.get_chart_2;
            break;
    }            
    string output=  getChartMethod("asldkl");
}
```

If there were a lot, you could just create an array instead of using a switch. Obviously you could just run the appropriate function directly from the switch, but I assume that the idea is you may want to pass the delegate back to the caller, and a construct like this lets you do that without using reflection, e.g.

```
public static Func<string,object> GetMethod
{
 ... just return getChartMethod directly
}
```

Comment: yah...yours maybe a solution also if I am not forced to use delegate only.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a method on `Delegate` **type**. You have to use `DynamicInvoke()` which is *very slowwwwwww*.

Try this:

```
string output = (string) del.DynamicInvoke(new object[]{"asldkl"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Delegate` class not the `delegate` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call delegates with method call syntax, if they have a known signature. You need to cast your delegate to the delegate type you defined earlier.

```
var del = (PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty), obj, "get_Chart_" + i.ToString());
```

You also need to change the first argument to `CreateDelegate`, because it should be the delegate type. And capitalize the "C" in "get_Chart_".

And then, you will need to cast the returned `object` to `string`:

```
string output= (string) del("asldkl");
```

Or change the delegate type and the methods to have `string` as their return type.

Comment: getProperty is not visible to Main. So Edited this way-> 

PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty del = (PropertyRetrievalClass.getProperty) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PropertyRetrievalClass), obj, "get_chart_" + i.ToString() );           

            string output=  new del("asldkl");


**************
It doesn't work either...I got this error-> The type or namespace name 'del' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)